# stop cosuming messages temprorry for a certain time in rabbitmq?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I have a requirement that I want to stop the consumption queue for a few minutes from a function call and after some time I want resume the consumption from the queue. Please tell how we can handle this in rabbitmq node js?

Comment: I think you can use delay header while publishing event

Comment: do you actually want to stop consuming - meaning you don't want the messages to be "received" on the consumer side OR you want to delay the processing of messages?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to stop the `consumers` or the `publishers` of the rabbitmq.

This will entail implementing an on/off switch for a queue usage (you can use `rabbitmq` as well to notify if a certain queue should be used or not).

### Option 1 - (stop publishers)

If you will implement this switch as a part of the `publishers` you will **stop** publishing messages to the queue. The consumers will finish what is already in the queue and will wait till new messages are avilable.

Pros:

1. you keep your queue clean when you stop (no hanging jobs)

Cons:

1. consumers are still working (if the queue already have messages)
2. what do you do with the request if you can't publish them to the queue (maybe drop them but this is up to you and what you are trying to achieve)

### Option 2 - (stop consumers)

If you will implement this switch as a part of the `consumers` you will be able to drop all the handled requests and re-queue them. In addition you will still be accumulation messages because your publishers are still working.

Pros:

1. you can keep accumulation messages even when you are not "stoping"

Cons:

1. You can overpopulate the queue with messages if no consumers are working